# jQuery: Displaying text dependent on dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I have a select box with values automatically assigned and need to convert the values to display a certain string of text further down the page.

For example:

- Option 1 value 3111 = abc
- Option 2 value 3112 = def
- Option 3 value 3113 = ghi
- etc...

If user selects `Option 1` it should reference something saying value equals abc and display `abc`.

I believe I can grab the value of the dropdown using `$(this).val()`, but how do I add this in to a string to say if value equals 3111 echo abc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#options").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3111":
            alert("abc");
        break;
        case "3112":
            alert("def");
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("myOption").change(function(){
    $("#displayDiv").html($(this).val());
});
```

Or use a switch to convert from the value to the display string and insert that instead.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to map dropdown values to your texts

```
var dropdown_maps = {
    '3111': 'abc',
    '3112': 'def'
}
```

Then use this to check with your dropdown

```
$('#my-dropdown').change(function(){

    var v = $(this).val();
    // e.g. v = '3111'
    if (v in dropdown_maps) {
        // result in 'abc';
       console.log(dropdown_maps[v]); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the value of the drop down directly by examining the selected option.

```
$('#MySelect').change(function() {
   $('#DisplayDiv').html($('#MySelect option:selected').text());
});​
```

Comment: The 2nd line could be a bit neater: $('#DisplayDiv').html($('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' option:selected').text());